# Can't acces models in new Namespace

Tags: php, zend-framework, propel, zend-acl

I use the Propel ORM for my models & mapping. My Models are under /models. 
I've added a line to my index.php file to make sure that he finds my models:

```
// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
   realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
   realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models'),//propel
   get_include_path(),
)));
```

I can use the query's in my modules, that works fine. But when I want to use it in my Acl Helper he can't find the models ... .

I've created a namespace in my Zend Framework project called "GentseFeesten".
I've added this to my Bootstrap.php:

```
protected function _initAutoload() 
{
    $moduleLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        'namespace' => '',
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH));
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->registerNamespace('GentseFeesten_');
    return $moduleLoader;
}
```

In my GentseFeesten library I have:

> - Controller
>
>   - Helper
>   - Plugin

And in Helper I have "Acl.php". I have a function setRoles() :

```
private function setRoles() {

    // Database query
    $roles = RoleQuery::create()
        ->orderById()
        ->find();

    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        if($parentrole == 0)
        {
            $this->local_acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role($role->getRole()));
        }
        else{
            $this->local_acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role($role->getRole()), $parentrole);
        }
        $parentrole = $role->getRole();
    }
}
```

But the RoleQuery can't be found. The error:

> Fatal error: Class 'RoleQuery' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/GentseFeesten/library/GentseFeesten/Controller/Helper/Acl.php on line 35

I've included my Acl Plugin in Bootstrap like this:

```
new GentseFeesten_Controller_Helper_Acl($this->getResource('frontController'));
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $frontController->registerPlugin(new GentseFeesten_Controller_Plugin_Acl());
```

Does anyone know why he can't find my models in the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to initialize the propel plugin first and then the acl plugin ... . Just changed the position of the two functions and it worked!